# Are efficient fixed-size arrays possible without using unsafe code in .NET?

Tags: c#, arrays, unsafe

Is there a *good* way of implementing a fixed-size array in .NET that does not require unsafe code?

My goal is to create a value type which represents a fixed-size array which can be embedded (included as a member) in other types - i.e. I'm specifically hoping to avoid creating an array as a seperate object to the type which declares it.

I realize that .NET's implementation of arrays is superb and supported at CLR/CIL level - and don't really want to debate whether or not to just use arrays... the exploration here is to whether or not a safe, fixed-size, value type implementation is possible with *almost as good* efficiency.

Comment: Can you help me understand what benefit this provides that an ordinary array (declared within the type) cannot? It's hard to come up with an alternate implementation if I don't even know what the objective is. Is this about eliminating some of the objections to arrays outlined here?: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Comment: @Robert: The objective is to be able to have a fixed-size value-type array which can be used as a private member on other types. Consider a custom dictionary or linked-list implementation... the number of heap allocations can be reduced if each bucket/node is flattened to contain it's own, fixed-size array.

Answer (score 5):

> The objective is to be able to have a
> fixed-size value-type array which can
> be used as a private member on other
> types. Consider a custom dictionary or
> linked-list implementation... the
> number of *heap allocations* can be
> reduced if each bucket/node is
> flattened to contain it's own,
> fixed-size array.

Making your array a value type does not necessarily mean it's going to be stored on the stack. In fact, if it's a value type embedded within a reference type, it's most likely going to be stored on the heap with the reference type, and not on the stack.

So making it a value type will not reduce heap allocations at all.

More info [here](https://ericlippert.com/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/).

Comment: Yup, this will end up on the heap.  And he'll end up copying this 512 byte struct many times, no doubt.

Comment: The idead behind this question was specifically aimed at embedding the struct into a class and having the struct allocated on the heap with the class. If implemented as a private member and used correctly, it should not be copied around many times.

Comment: ...and it will reduce heap allocations since it now allocates just once (for the containing class) and not again for the array.

Answer (score 2):

After some research using reflector, it turns out that the following represents an acceptable (performance-wise) solution, since C# compiles a switch statement against integers into a CIL switch statement, which is implemented as a jump-list... that is - the getter executes in about 11 CIL instructions, which it fine.

```
 public struct EmbeddedArray<T>
    {
        private T _element0;
        private T _element1;
        private T _element2;

        public int Length { get { return 3; } }


        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (index)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return _element0;
                    case 1:
                        return _element1;
                    case 2:
                        return _element2;
                }
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

            }
        }
    }
```

---

Please see Hans' comment below. It turns out that this is *not* as performant as I'd hoped... once the CIL is compiled to native machine code, the measured performance is far off what a .NET array will yield.

Comment: Looking at IL is meaningless, only the machine code that the jitter generates is relevant.  And this code should perform a *lot* worse than an array index.  It has very poor cache locality due to the large jump table.  And an almost guaranteed branch misprediction which are *very* expensive on modern cores.  An array index has none of these problems.  Profile it to see this, use real data.

Comment: @Hans - Much respect, again, for your comment. Adfter doing a little profiling, it turns out that you're indeed correct... the IL switch statement was a little misleading. Also, the cost of allocating an array seperately from the class that uses it is a very inexpensive price to pay for the performance gains of an array. Thumbs up, Hans - I wish you'd posted an answer insterad of a comment - it would be the accepted answer here.

Comment: The last paragraph in your question excluded the possibility of talking about the right answer.